# Is it possible to do Self Join of a Temporary table in SQL query

Tags: sql, temp-tables, self-join

SQL queries are relatively new for me. Started learning the same.
I have a question.

Is it possible to do Self Join of a Temporary table?
If so, could you please give an example.

Thanks in advance for any possible help you provide on this.

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: Yes.  You can do a self join on any tables, including temporary tables.

Comment: I think the only DBMS that does not allow this is MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

In sql Server it is possible. I have table as follows

```
#tmpEmployee(Id Int, Ename Varchar(150), ManagerId INT)
```

I want to show result containing Id, EName, Manager then query will be

```
SELECT t.Id, t.Ename, x.Ename [Manager] FROM #tmpEmployee t INNER JOIN #tmpEmployee x ON t.ManagerId = x.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Mysql does not allow self-join on temporary tables. It fails with error : "Can't reopen table"

See this : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html

Answer (score 0):

The limitation prevents the same temp table from being referenced more than once within the same query. However, you can refer to the table in different queries. So you can workaround this limitation by creating a second instance of the temp table.

```
create temporary table t2(...);

insert into t2 
select * from t1;
```

Now you can join `t1` and `t2`.