# MySQL - How to optimize query with multiple dependent subqueries to independent?

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization

Given the following query, how can I optimize it so that the subqueries are not dependent?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    inst.id, inst.name, inst.state, inst.farm_status,
    (SELECT COUNT(inst_note.id) 
        FROM project_institution_note AS inst_note
        WHERE inst_note.institution_id = inst.id) AS inst_note_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM project_catalog AS c
        WHERE c.institution_id = inst.id 
        AND c.status = 0 
        AND c.catalog_type BETWEEN 0 AND 1) AS ug_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM project_catalog AS c
        WHERE c.institution_id = inst.id 
        AND c.status = 0 
        AND c.catalog_type BETWEEN 1 AND 2) AS grad_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM project_catalog AS c
        WHERE c.institution_id = inst.id 
        AND c.status = 0 AND c.catalog_type >= 3) AS alt_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM project_catalog_note AS cn
        INNER JOIN farmtool_catalog AS c
        ON c.id = cn.catalog_id
        WHERE c.institution_id = inst.id) AS catalog_note_count,
    (SELECT inst_note.text FROM project_institution_note AS inst_note
        LEFT JOIN project_institution AS inst
        ON inst_note.institution_id = inst.id
        WHERE inst_note.institution_id = inst.id
        ORDER BY inst_note.date DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS latest_note
FROM project_institution AS inst
LEFT JOIN project_institution_note AS inst_note
ON inst.id = inst_note.institution_id
LEFT JOIN project_catalog AS c
ON inst.id = c.institution_id
WHERE LOWER(inst.state) = "me";
```

I've tried refactoring the first subquery into an `INNER JOIN` like so:

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(inst_note.id) 
        FROM project_institution_note AS inst_note
        GROUP BY inst_note.institution_id) inst_note_count 
        ON inst_note.institution_id = inst.id
```

and included it after the last `LEFT JOIN` operation, but returned an empty result.

Of particular interest for me is optimizing the second and third subqueries that calcuate `ug_count` and `grad_count`.  The only difference between the two is the first is dependent on a field value between (0, 1), and the second between (1, 2).

Right now, this query runs fine, and is in a low use scenario.  Still, its obviously pretty inefficient, so I'd like to optimize if possible.

Comment: i would use temporary tables. it keeps things clear and avoid all of these subqueries

Comment: Do you mean views?

Comment: no views are different from temporary table. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897323/what-to-use-view-or-temporary-table. i'll try to post an answer with some examples.

Answer (score 0):

This should hopefully get you part of the way.

```
SELECT 
    inst.id, inst.name, inst.state, inst.farm_status,
    COUNT(DISTINCT inst_note.id)  AS inst_note_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.status = 0 and c.catalog_type BETWEEN 0 AND 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ug_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.status = 0 and c.catalog_type BETWEEN 1 AND 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS grad_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.status = 0 and c.catalog_type >= 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS alt_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT cn.id) AS catalog_note_count,
    (SELECT inst_note.text FROM project_institution_note AS inst_note
        LEFT JOIN project_institution AS inst
        ON inst_note.institution_id = inst.id
        WHERE inst_note.institution_id = inst.id
        ORDER BY inst_note.date DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS latest_note
FROM project_institution AS inst
LEFT JOIN project_institution_note AS inst_note ON inst.id = inst_note.institution_id
LEFT JOIN project_catalog AS c ON inst.id = c.institution_id
LEFT JOIN farmtool_catalog AS fc ON fc.institution_id = inst.id
LEFT JOIN project_catalog_note AS cn ON fc.id = cn.catalog_id
WHERE LOWER(inst.state) = "me"
GROUP BY inst.id, inst.name, inst.state, inst.farm_status;
```

Not sure if you can do anything about getting the latest note. In Sql-Server I would use a cte and a window function, but these things are not available in MySql. I hope this is useful anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the biggest performance killer is

```
WHERE LOWER(inst.state) = "me";
```

Make the `COLLATION` for `state` be one of the `..._ci` collations (which it probably already is), then change to simply

```
WHERE inst.state = "me";
```

And be sure to have

```
INDEX(state)
```

Meanwhile, don't do this:

```
JOIN ... ON inst_note.institution_id = inst.id
      WHERE inst_note.institution_id = inst.id
```

The `ON` and `WHERE` are redundant and do exactly the same thing.  Since that is (I assume) how the tables are linked; keep the `ON`.  But...

That was really `LEFT JOIN...`, which means "keep the 'right' table even if there is no matching row.  But, then the `WHERE` will fail.  So...  Make it `JOIN` and get rid of the `WHERE` clause.

In general, don't use `LEFT` unless you need it.

For the original attempt, this (and some other 'composite' indexes) would be helpful:

```
project_catalog: INDEX(institution_id, status, catalog_type)
```

A potential performance problem with `JOIN` plus `GROUP BY` is an explosion, then implosion of rows being handled.  To avoid it, an improvement on Casey's suggestion is to have a derived table to calculate the various `SUMs`, then `JOIN` back to `inst`, now without the `GROUP BY`.  This avoids hauling around the 4 columns in the `GROUP BY` (and perhaps some other benefits).