# SQL Using PIVOT for multi valued attributes

Tags: sql-server, database, pivot, rows, multivalue

I designed an EAV table that looks like this:

```
SID  AID  VID
1     1    1
1     2    1
1     3    2
1     4    3
1     1    2
```

SID stand for Subject ID, AID stands for Attribute ID and VID stands for ValuedID

also a table to map the attributes:

```
AttributeID AttributeName
    1            Hobbies
    2            Name
    3            Gender
    4            IrisColor
```

After using pivot on the first table, linked to the attribute table:

```
SELECT
    SubjectID,
    Hobbies,
    Name,
    Gender,
    IrisColor       
FROM
(
SELECT SubjectID, attr.AttributeName as attribute, ValueID from SubjectDetails, SubjectAttributes as attr WHERE SubjectDetails.AttributeID=attr.ID
) as t
PIVOT(
MAX(ValueID) 

FOR attribute IN (Hobbies,Name,Gender,IrisColor)) AS t1

WHERE SubjectID=1
```

I get this:

```
SubjectID Hobbies Name Gender IrisColor
    1        1      1     2      3
```

Which is almost correct, but SubjectAttribute 1 (which is hobbies) appears one more time in the first table (SubjectDetails), so what I want to achieve is this:

```
SubjectID Hobbies Name Gender IrisColor
    1        **1,2**      1     2      3
```

I have to mention that I don't care about what separator is used and that I tried doing that with the STUFF function but it is a pain to combine PIVOT and STUFF (or I just don't know how).. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can modify your source EAV table so that it has one row per attribute with comma separated values and then pivot using your pivot query.

Comment: I cannot due that.. the requirement is to have separate rows for each attribute even if it repeats. I only wan't to do that in a view, but not as in storing it with comma separation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, I did the following:
Stored the information from your EAV table (`table1`) as single row per `SID` into a `temporary table` (you can create a `view` instead).
Then pivoted that resultset as below (using your pivot query):

```
SELECT *   
FROM
  (
     SELECT * from #temptbl
  ) as t
PIVOT( MAX(vid) FOR attrname IN (Hobbies,Name,Gender,IrisColor)) AS t1
WHERE sid=1
```

I got this result:

[image]

Please check the full working version [here](http://rextester.com/GKQ17108).

Comment: very nice! :) happy coding!

Comment: One more question, what is the best way, creating a view or recreating the table everytime?

Comment: It depends, but if the data does not change often you could keep it in a view. You could also try both scenarios and find out which one is faster! 
A temp table will do the trick everytime for sure. You can take a look at this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897323/what-to-use-view-or-temporary-table).

Comment: Ok, and about the solution, what I also wanted to try is to replace the 'MAX' function with another Aggregate function written by me which concatenates the given column

Answer (score 0):

This would work without using PIVOT, I think here no need to use PIVOT

```
SELECT  SubjectID
        ,+STUFF((SELECT ', '+CAST(ValueID AS NVARCHAR) 
                FROM @T_SubjectAttributes A 
                INNER JOIN @T_SubjectDetails B ON A.AttributeID = B.AttributeId
                WHERE AttributeName = 'Hobbies'
                AND B.SubjectID = H.SubjectID FOR XML PATH(''))
                        ,1,2,'')    AS Hobbies
        ,STUFF((SELECT ', '+CAST(ValueID AS NVARCHAR) 
                FROM @T_SubjectAttributes A 
                INNER JOIN @T_SubjectDetails B ON A.AttributeID = B.AttributeId
                WHERE AttributeName = 'Name' 
                AND B.SubjectID = H.SubjectID FOR XML PATH(''))
                        ,1,2,'')    AS Name
        ,STUFF((SELECT ', '+CAST(ValueID AS NVARCHAR) 
                FROM @T_SubjectAttributes A 
                INNER JOIN @T_SubjectDetails B ON A.AttributeID = B.AttributeId
                WHERE AttributeName = 'Gender' 
                AND B.SubjectID = H.SubjectID FOR XML PATH(''))
                        ,1,2,'')    AS Gender
        ,STUFF((SELECT ', '+CAST(ValueID AS NVARCHAR) 
                FROM @T_SubjectAttributes A 
                INNER JOIN @T_SubjectDetails B ON A.AttributeID = B.AttributeId
                WHERE AttributeName = 'IrisColor' 
                AND B.SubjectID = H.SubjectID FOR XML PATH(''))
                        ,1,2,'')    AS IrisColor
FROM @T_SubjectDetails H
GROUP BY SubjectID
```