# Multiple SELECTs from one nested SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, nested

I'm running multiple SELECTs in one query, and they are using the same nested FROM SELECT.
The code goes something like this:

```
SELECT B FROM (SELECT A) DATA; 
SELECT C FROM (SELECT A) DATA;
SELECT D FROM (SELECT A) DATA;
SELECT E FROM (SELECT A) DATA
```

Is there a way to "store" SELECT A (variable? other way?) and use it across this one query or do I need to repeat it every single time? SELECT A is quite large and I'd like to make this query as clean as possible.

Comment: Create a `VIEW`?

Comment: This is it! I know it was a *facepalm* question, but that was as far as my knowledge got me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Oh, there's a variety of options, depending on your use case:

1. If the nested SELECT never changes, you can [create a view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).
2. If all the statements are executed in the same session and the filtering is mostly done in the nested SQL, you can select its result into [a temp table or a temp variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27894/87698).
3. If those SQL statements are created in code, you can create a [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (CTE). Yes, you still need to include the CTE in every single SQL, but you only have to append it at the *beginning* of each SELECT statement rather than *in the middle*, which might make your code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `VIEW` so that you only have to write the A query once, but if you only want to execute the data within the query once, you can also save the data in a variable. You can read about the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897323/view-or-temporary-table-which-to-use-in-ms-sql-server). Example below.

```
DECLARE @A TABLE (
    B NVARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
,   C INT NOT NULL
,   D NVARCHAR(250) NULL
)

INSERT INTO @A (B, C, D)
SELECT 
    [ColumnB]
,   [ColumnC]
,   [ColumnD]
FROM [dbo].[MyTable] 

SELECT [B] FROM @A; 
SELECT [C] FROM @A; 
SELECT [D] FROM @A;
```

Answer (score 0):

first solution
Execute the query as text

```
declare @QuerySub_Str  Nvarchar(500);
set @QuerySub_Str ='SELECT A'
declare @QueryFinal_Str Nvarchar(4000);
set @QueryFinal_Str = 'SELECT B FROM (' + @QuerySub_Str +') DATA; 
SELECT C FROM (' + @QuerySub_Str +') DATA;
SELECT D FROM (' + @QuerySub_Str +') DATA;
SELECT E FROM (' + @QuerySub_Str +' DATA;'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

the best solution
Create a view containing the partial query
Use it in the final query

```
Create VIEW [dbo].[View_1]
AS
SELECT  1 as A , 2 As B  , 3 As C , 4 As D  , 5 As E  
FROM            Table_1
GO

SELECT B FROM View_1 ; 
SELECT C FROM View_1 ;
SELECT D FROM View_1 ;
SELECT E FROM View_1 ;
```